# Get all path siblings in SVG

Tags: jquery, svg

Is it possible to get all path siblings in an svg?

So if I roll over a path I can apply css to all the others.

I have tried using .siblings(), but no joy yet. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Code of first 2 path items is:

```
<path id="Fill-1" fill="#CED837" stroke="#fff" d="M59.504,79.62c-2.85-0.498-8.781,0.231-10.686,1.214c-1.899,0.977-2.849,1.708-5.225,1.702
            c-2.367-0.005-4.26-5.266-5.442-4.476c-1.19,0.782-4.995,2.74-7.13,3.226c-2.133,0.486-3.324,0.237-3.563,1.22
            c-0.241,0.989,1.405,9.332-0.019,10.071c-1.423,0.735-2.372,1.462-3.564,1.954c-1.188,0.49-3.797,0.484-3.797,0.484
            s-2.14,2.2-2.616,2.94c-0.474,0.734,1.905,0.25-2.372,0.976l-4.275,0.733c0,0,1.642,8.104-0.017,8.836
            c-1.659,0.735-3.798,0.977-2.848,2.45c0.948,1.479,2.366,2.947,2.601,4.427c0.236,1.467,0.469,1.958,1.413,3.191"/>
        <path id="Fill-3" fill="#CED837" class="test"  d="M226.231,139.39l-4.681-0.007l-3.035-7.112l5.933-4.998l-0.992-4.124l-6.329-0.017l-4.502-6.226
            l3.443-3.543c-2.097-6.671-4.164-14.63-2.969-16.882c0.302-0.565,0.781-0.963,1.364-1.113c0.667-0.334,2.123-3.206,3.019-6.011
            l0.372-1.188l2.592,0.006l1.104-3.681l-1.792-11.676l-5.878-0.013l-0.577-8.544l-2.944-3.059l2.716-7.1
            c-1.791-0.512-4.327-1.412-5.66-0.715c-1.912,0.969-5.711,1.945-6.419,4.401c-0.723,2.45-0.012,3.438-1.91,3.182
            c-1.901-0.247-7.357-0.991-9.25-0.999c-1.904,0-4.034-1.965-3.795-4.42c0.243-2.456-0.694-7.369-1.88-8.849
            c-1.183-1.472-1.424-0.484-3.083-2.706c-1.657-2.206-2.127-4.661-3.071-4.661c-0.955,0-7.127,3.91-6.894,6.614
            c0.229,2.7,2.117,7.61,1.647,8.841c-0.481,1.22-0.493,2.209-1.677,3.682c-1.186,1.468-4.274,1.462-4.982,3.427
            c-0.723,1.957,0.702,2.206-1.906,3.188c-2.614,0.97-7.127,4.154-9.502,4.154c-2.38-0.008-15.885-8.375-17.309-8.134
            c-1.425,0.243-7.128,2.438-7.838,3.912c-0.721,1.473-1.195,2.947-4.045,3.916c-2.85,0.982-4.741-0.498-5.224,0.977
            c-0.474,1.467-0.965,9.227-3.576,8.289c-2.602-0.934-7.114-2.413-7.823-2.668c-0.717-0.243-2.136-0.741-3.323,0
            c-1.192,0.732-3.799,0.38-4.521,2.644c-0.708,2.256-3.101,8.878-4.52,9.363c-1.429,0.491-2.613,1.721-3.564,1.225
            c-0.943-0.492-1.879-7.368-2.354-8.357c-0.475-0.977-5.222-3.93-6.401-3.688c-1.188,0.236-9.502,4.646-10.457,5.627
            c-0.949,0.978-1.905,5.149-3.329,6.131c-0.59,0.404-1.418,0.766-2.201,1.051l-2.234,6.305c3.029,0.305,6.124,0.348,6.918-0.062
            c2.107-1.086,3.946,0.379,5.294,1.442c0.541,0.435,1.376,1.102,1.72,1.102l7.133,0.044c0.127,0.025,3.264,0.708,5.187,3.375"
            />
```

Many thanks,

Greig

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If I run `console.log($('#Fill-1').siblings().andSelf().length);` I get `2` what is the problem with that?

Comment: By roll over do you mean `:hover` property of CSS? Because that can be done even without using jQuery